# Insert into ... select columns from table .... join #temptable

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, select, sql-insert

As you can see, I'm new here. Also new to SQL Server. I've been using SSMS for two weeks now. So I'm learning and have new problems every day. This problem seems not to be a big one; however, I cant handle it.

I have a string:

```
' texttype;commment|texttype2;comment2'
```

which I have to split and put into column comments as new insert in existing table column. I already did use `SPLIT` function which produces this in `#temptable`:

```
items
--------
texttype;commment
texttype2;comment2
```

Then I used substring and charindex to have this in #temptable2:

```
types                | commentary
---------------------+------------
texttype             | commment
texttype2            | comment2
```

I have to insert this comment and comment2 into a specific existing table from this #temptable2

And here is my question: how to do that? What kind of Join use? ofc destination table has more than two columns. No idea how to define this insert/join from #temptable2

Destination table looks similar to:

```
ID | ID_Jobs | Column for comments | Column for types | A few more columns
```

I hope I'm all clear.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you provide a minimal code example of what you have so far? What I am seeing above is more of a running commentary of your results but I don't actually see any source code (unless I'm missing something).

Comment: Code is a mess yet, im going sleep now, ill try to specify tommorow for sure, thx for reply

Answer (score 1):

sorry for bothering... already work.. i did simple mistake by join same table, without it problem solved.. maybe it might help someone so i past complete code here:

```
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE AddCommentToJobFromString (
        @ID_JOBS int, 
        @CommentString nvarchar(2000),
        @OPERACTIVE INT
        )
AS 
BEGIN
        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#temp', 'U') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #temp;

SELECT * into #temp from dbo.Split(@CommentString , '|') as t1
SELECT 
        SUBSTRING(t.items, 1 , CHARINDEX(';',t.items)-1) as typuwag,
        SUBSTRING(t.items,  CHARINDEX(';',t.items)+1, LEN(t.items)) as trescuwagi
INTO #temp2 
FROM #temp t 

INSERT INTO Uwagi (ID_Jobs, Uwaga, ID_TypyUwag, ID_Operatorzy_Creator, ID_Operatorzy_Last, DateCreated, LastModified)
--DECLARE @OPERACTIVE INT = 4628
--DECLARE @ID_JOBS INT = 65141
Select  
        @ID_JOBS,
        t2.trescuwagi,  
        TU.ID,
        @OPERACTIVE,
        @OPERACTIVE,
        getdate(),
        getdate()
        --t2.typuwag




FROM TypyUwag TU
inner join #temp2 t2
ON TU.TypUwagi = t2.typuwag  COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT

END
GO
EXEC AddCommentToJobFromString @ID_JOBS = 65141, @CommentString ='qwe;Tech visual check|Kosztorys;Estimate not ready yet', @OPERACTIVE = 4628
```

Answer (score 0):

You will most certainly need to modify this to fit your situation (e.g. table names, extra columns, etc.), but I think this is what you need.

```
CREATE TABLE SourceTable
(
    MyString VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE TargetTable
(
    TextType VARCHAR(25)
  , Comment VARCHAR(25)
);

INSERT INTO SourceTable
(
    MyString
)
VALUES
('texttype;commment|texttype2;comment2');

SELECT * FROM SourceTable

INSERT INTO TargetTable
(
    TextType
  , Comment
)
SELECT
            LEFT(value, CHARINDEX(';', value) - 1)           AS TextTypeColumn
          , RIGHT(value, LEN(value) - CHARINDEX(';', value)) AS CommentColumn
FROM        SourceTable
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(MyString, '|');

SELECT * FROM TargetTable;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cc61cff8b724fbcddf913b5fbdc94972)